# Element not enabled

Tags: python, automation, element, ui-automation, pywinauto

Using a script a modder made for a tool for modding a game.

```
verify_enabledpywinauto.base_wrapper.ElementNotEnabled
```

What does that mean?

Tried running the script instead of the auto script file that didn't need python to run to cause it used pywinauto through Python and still the same result.

```
start merging mod index =  0
this mod provides regulation.bin
start opening regulation.bin
finished opening regulation.bin

Traceback (most recent call last):  File "automateYapped.py", line 334,
 in <module>  File "automateYapped.py", line 305, in main
  File "automateYapped.py", line 70, in massExport
  File "pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 715, in menu_select
  File "pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 681, in verify_actionable
  File "pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 692, in verify_enabled
pywinauto.base_wrapper.ElementNotEnabled
```

That's what goes on when I run the script.

Mind you it was working just fine then just stopped out of nowhere. The creator of the script hasn't responded yet.

The program the script automated is called Yapped. This script is called automateYapped.

Comment: It means some element is not enabled. Please provide full traceback and code snippet by editing your question. I can't help without more detailed information. Any guide how to prepare technical description of a bug should be helpful.

Comment: So basically just copy the whole process up to the error? Just wanna make sure I give you the right stuff needed.

Comment: Well, you need to look into `"automateYapped.py", line 70, in massExport` and check in the application which menu item is not enabled which was expected to be enabled by the script at this step. Python usually provides detailed enough error messages.